# How would you implement a working queue in etcd

Tags: queue, distributed, etcd, workload

I have just started to look into **etcd** and one of the use cases that is mentioned in the talks given by the creators, is a work queue system.

But how would you actually implement this?

Basic pattern would be something like this.

1 process generating "work description tickets", and place that ticket in a folder of etcd lets say "/queue/worktickets/00000000001/"

1->many processes listening to the "/queue/worktickets/" folder for changes.
when a new work ticket appears every process wil try to *grab* the ticket by creating a new value in "/queue/locks/00000001" to lock that ticket. Only the first one will be able to create the lock value.

The process that created the lock ticket does it's work, and then removes the ticket from the queue, and maybe the lock value. Then try to grab the next available ticket from the queue. If no more tickets available, start listening to changes in the "/queue/worktickets/" folder again.

In my head this should be fairly simple to implement, but if the queue gets large(ticket is easy to generate but hard to process) then it seems there will be a lot of data being transeferd from etcd to each of the clients. 
To my knowledege there is no way of saying give me the first value in this folder that does not exist in this folder nor is there some give me top n items from folder.

Anyone care to share their thougths on this.

Comment: The etcd repo has contributed recipes that include a [queue](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/contrib/recipes/queue.go), which might be useful to you.

Answer (score 4):

So I came up with a solution that I think is robust.  Here are the goals that I designed my solution for:

- It should be efficient (i.e. O(1) network roundtrips) for a worker to retrieve an item from the work queue.
- If a worker dies or otherwise fails while it's processing an item, the item becomes available to other workers.

So the idea is to have two queues: a pending queue and a running queue.  Originally all items are in the pending queue.

When a worker tries to retrieve an item, it transfers it from the pending queue to the running queue using a transaction (available in etcd 3).  In the same transaction, the worker also creates a lock for the item.  The lock is guarded by a lease, so it's automatically removed if the worker dies.

If a worker successfully finishes processing the item, it removes the item from the running queue and we are done.  If the worker fails, the lock will expire, and the item is left in the running queue.

Thus, workers are also expected to look into the running queue once the pending queue has been exhausted.  The expectation is that the running queue will be small comparing to the pending queue, thus finding an item that's currently not locked (by simply listing the running queue) is not going to be expensive.

Or as @dannysauer mentioned in the comments, you could also have another fault-tolerant process that transfers items from the running queue back to the pending queue.

Comment: Thanks Derek and @dannysauer for the great answers. I'm needing to implement something similar with potentially large (100kB) values. Rather than copying to a pending folder, which seems expensive, would it be more efficient to just check matching locks and take the oldest "work item"  that doesn't have a corresponding lock and then try to create a lock? I'm assuming reading keys in etcd is a lot cheaper than trying to create one.  Seems like this would also catch any items whose locks expire.

Comment: It's been a while so I could be wrong but I don't think it's possible to `check matching locks and take the oldest "work item" that doesn't have a corresponding lock` in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you've already solved this problem, but the way I'd do it is to  list the contents of the work queue directory (which is what you get when you fetch the directory anyway).  Then just start going down the list attempting to create identically-named locks in the lock directory until you get a lock.  The creation of the lock "file" is atomic if you use the "prevExist=false" flag, so if you successfully created it, you are the one who has the lock on that item.

Ideally, you'd have a rough estimate of how long it should take to process the item, and you set the TTL to slightly longer than that (or you refresh the TTL periodically after steps which have a time you can estimate).  Either you delete the item from the original queue (and maybe recreate in a "completed" directory) when you're done, or your lock expires and someone else picks it up.

Also, ideally you'd put your unique "node identifier" (hostname, whatever) into the lock file, so your TTL updates do a compare-and-set, which will fail if you lost the lock for taking too long.

The work directory would presumably have items created sequentially using a POST on the directory, while the lock queue and completed directory would have items created by name using a PUT.

Comment: But what if you have a lot of items in the work queue?  You certainly don't want to try to lock them one by one.  Is there any way to efficiently retrieve an item that's not locked?

Comment: If you have a lot of clients, you would use a couple of queues. Jobs come in to a "pending" queue, clients then move a pending job to an "in progress" queue when a client is processing the job, then either moved to a completed queue on completion or removed. You'd need something to watch the locks and move stuff from in-progress back to pending if they aren't finished before the lock expires.

Comment: An alternate approach would be to have the work queue use sequentially numbers entries (which etcd will do for you) and then use a counter which each client does an atomic increment on. You don't have to lay the directory that way, as you just fetch the one item corresponding with the counter. But then you have a single point of contention that all clients depend upon,  which might be a problem depending on the work definition.

Comment: I posted a solution that's similar to the multi-queue approach you mentioned.  Regarding the sequentially-named approach: I think it works great for distributing items, but it's unclear how you'd "return" an item back to the queue if the worker fails, since the counter would've advanced past the item.

Comment: Yeah; with the counter you'd still need a cleanup operation which checks for incomplete jobs if incomplete jobs are a concern. I don't like the single shared lock for everything anyway, most of the time.